# oracle failed triggers validation

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

Imagine there are 2 triggers like

```
create or replace TRIGGER A AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
```

and

```
create or replace TRIGGER B AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
```

(note on schema). Both are invalid (fail to execute) and you need to drop them.

If you try to drop trigger A you get:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

ORA-04098: trigger 'USER.B' is invalid and failed re-validation
04045. 00000 -  "errors during recompilation/revalidation of %s.%s"
*Cause:    This message indicates the object to which the following
           errors apply.  The errors occurred during implicit
           recompilation/revalidation of the object.
*Action:   Check the following errors for more information, and
           make the necessary corrections to the object.
Vendor code 4045
```

and vice versa.

How would you drop the triggers?

Comment: Please post https://dbfiddle.uk demo to show recreate your case

Comment: 1. Try an ALTER TRIGGER disable, then drop. 2 Since you wouldn't have been able to create the second trigger if the fitst was invalid, I assume something was changed that invalidated them. Change that back so they can be validated, then drop.